# Java constructor undefined

Tags: java

Basically, I was doing a Java exercise in a book and this source code is its answer to the exercise. However, eclipse says there is an error at the third line up from the bottom, saying "- The constructor PhoneNumber() is undefined". But as I understand, that specific constructor is defined correctly so what is the problem?

```
public class PhoneNumber {
    // Only the relevant source codes are posted here.
    // I removed other bits cause I'm sure they are not responsible for the
    // error

    private char[] country;
    private char[] area;
    private char[] subscriber;

    public PhoneNumber(final String country, final String area, final String subscriber) {
        this.country = new char[country.length()];
        country.getChars(0, country.length(), this.country, 0);
        this.area = new char[area.length()];
        area.getChars(0, area.length(), this.area, 0);
        this.subscriber = new char[subscriber.length()];
        subscriber.getChars(0, subscriber.length(), this.subscriber, 0);
        checkCorrectness();
    }

    private void runTest() {
        // method body
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        (new PhoneNumber()).runTest(); // error here saying :
                                        // "The constructor PhoneNumber() is undefined"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eclipse is correct. Your code does not define a constructor with no arguments, which is what you are calling with `new PhoneNumber()` inside the `main` method.

You have only one constructor, which is:

```
public PhoneNumber (final String country, final String area, final String subscriber)
```

The so called *default constructor*, the one with no arguments, is automatically created for you if you don't specify any other constructor. Since you specify one with 3 parameters, you have no default constructor.

There are 2 ways to solve this:

1. Declare the no-arg constructor; or
2. Use the constructor you already have.

To implement the first option, you could do something like the following:

```
class PhoneNumber {
  ...
  public PhoneNumber() {
    this("no country", "no area", "no subscriber");
  }
}
```

This would create a no-arg constructor that simply calls the constructor you already have with a default set of parameters. This may or may not be what you want

To implement the second option, change your `main` method. Instead of

```
(new PhoneNumber ()).runTest();
```

use something like:

```
(new PhoneNumber("the country", "the area", "the subscriber")).runTest();
```

Answer (score 1):

The default (no argument) constructor is only defined automatically for you if you don't define any other constructor.

Answer (score 0):

What your error says is that no

```
PhoneNumber()
```

constructor is defined (without params). By default, this is the constructor that you have available in Java if you don't declare any other constructor. But you're overriding it by implementing

```
PhoneNumber (final String country, final String area, final String subscriber)
```