# Casting List<String> to List<ClassType> in java(android)

Tags: java, android

How can I cast `List<String>` with `List<HeaderInfo>`
**HeaderInfo** is my class name

```
public class HeaderInfo{
  public HeaderInfo(List<String> list){}
  public HeaderInfo(){}
}

public SomeClass{
  List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();
  lables = getAllLabels();
  List<HeaderInfo> lables1 = new ArrayList<HeaderInfo>(lables);
}
```

I wanted to convert `lables` to type `List<HeaderInfo>` so that I can pass it to my custom `adapter`

says undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want ??

```
    class HeaderInfo  {
    private List<String>list;
    public HeaderInfo(List<String> list){
    this.list = list;
  }

    public List<String> getList() {
    return list;
  }

    public HeaderInfo(){}

 }

  public class Test {

  public static void main(String a[])
  {

    List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>(getAllLabels());
    HeaderInfo headerInfo = new HeaderInfo(lables);
    List<HeaderInfo> lables1 = new ArrayList<HeaderInfo>();
    lables1.add(headerInfo);
    for(Object list : lables1)
    {
        HeaderInfo headerInfo1 = (HeaderInfo)list;
        System.out.println(headerInfo.getList().toString());

    }

}

private static List<String> getAllLabels() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("a");
    list.add("b");
    list.add("c");
    list.add("d");
    return list;
}
}
```

Comment: Nothing special you can do it like this also  'for(HeaderInfo header : lables1)' i was just trying to use the super-class of HeaderInfo

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `List<String>` as a parameter to the constructor of a new `ArrayList<HeaderInfo>`.

```
List<HeaderInfo> headerList = new ArrayList<HeaderInfo>(lables);
```

Any `Collection` can be passed as an argument to the constructor as long as its type extends the type of the `ArrayList`, as String extends `Object`. The constructor takes a `Collection`, but `List` is a subinterface of Collection, so you can just use the `List<String>`
Or

```
List<HeaderInfo> headerList = Arrays.asList(lables.toArray());
```

Comment: Type mismatch after using 2nd suggestion :(

Comment: And what about first?

Comment: Error: The constructor ArrayList<HeaderInfo>(List<String>) is undefined :(

Comment: 2nd suggestion says Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Object> to List<HeaderInfo>

Comment: @Nitish your class constructor is wrong. see this  post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071149/java-constructor-undefined

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you wanted to do is the following:

```
public SomeClass
{
    public List<HeaderInfo> getHeaderInfos()
    {
         List<String> labels = getAllLabels();
         List<HeaderInfo> headerInfos = new ArrayList<HeaderInfo>();
         for(String label : labels)
         {
             headerList.add(new HeaderInfo(label));
         }
         return headerInfos;
    }
}
```

Although here I assumed that a HeaderInfo contains only one String as a label. And that your constructor was wrong in this case. The getAllLabels() should return a

```
List<List<String>>
```

if that is not the case.

Comment: If it works as intended, please accept as the correct answer with the tick on the left :)